# scoreboard specification

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im in need for a way to detect if a scoreboard is set to 0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,or 4
And give the person that has that scoreboard certain items like, an enchanted diamond pickaxe or jump boost 2. Im playing MC 1.9.2. I also only want to use commands and redstone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Create a scorboard:*
(replace testBoard with a name for the scoreboard)

> /scoreboard objectives add testBoard dummy

*Set a value:*

> /scoreboard players set PLAYER_NAME testBoard 1

Testfor players with values:

*1. Effect*
(Replace the 1 with whatever score you want to test for)

**PUT THIS INTO A REPEATING COMMAND BLOCK**

> /effect @a[score_testBoard=1,score_testBoard_min=1] minecraft:jump_boost DURATION LEVEL

For example:

> /effect @a[score_testBoard=1,score_testBoard_min=1] minecraft:jump_boost 1 2

*2. Give items*
(Replace the 1 with whatever score you want to test for)

> /give @a[score_testBoard=1,score_testBoard_min=1] minecraft:dirt

If you want to give the item only once:

- Put the command into a repeating command block
- Add another repeating command block with the following command:
  (Replace the 1 with whatever score you want to test for)

> /scoreboard players reset @a[score_testBoard=1,score_testBoard_min=1] testBoard

*Then reset the value of an player:*

> /scoreboard players reset PLAYER_NAME testBoard

Hope it helped :)